# Escape character in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen similar topics in the internet but I can't find the appropriate one that will suit to my problem. I will shorten my discussion since it is too long to discuss. So I need to concatenate Column A, Column B, and Column C separated by "¦". I need to split using "¦" (no need to ask why I need to concatenate ¦ and then split it using ¦ - it is a long process. This is only a gist), but there is a possibility that the data contains "¦". Is it possible to disregard or escape first the "¦" in the data, so that it will not be consider as a delimiter? Changing of delimiter can also appear in the data. I am doing a form so I need to use VBA.

For example,

```
Column A     | Column B     | Column C     | Column D
111          | AAA          | 1A1          | 111¦AAA¦1A1
222          | BBB          | 2B2          | 222¦BBB¦2B2
333          | CC¦C         | 3C3          | 333¦CC¦C¦3C3
```

If I split the above example, it will look like this and which is wrong.

```
Column A     | Column B     | Column C     | Column D
111          | AAA          | 1A1          | 
222          | BBB          | 2B2          | 
333          | CC           | C            | 3C3
```

Comment: What is the reason that you have to use that specific delimiter?

Comment: Can't you use "Fixed width" while using the text import wizard? Once the text is imported in Excel, you can replace the `|` character by an empty character.

Comment: @Rory - I can't think of the other characters that impossible to used in the data. But, didn't expect when I tried to generate a report and was messed up. So, when I checked the customer's data there is a ¦. I am doing a form, so I need to use VBA.

Comment: @Dominique - I am doing a form, so I need to use VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can replace `|` by the character that you don't use, e.g by `^` (or with some pattern, e.g. `[ThisIsPipe]`), and during `split()`(or after) replace back `^` (or injected pattern) by `|` for instance.

IMHO, for [concatenation ~~> split] will be better to use those characters that are not reflected in sheet

Comment: Agreed. I like to use something in the unprintable range like `Chr$(30)` (record separator) or `Chr$(7)` (bell) for stuff like this.

Comment: @Vasily - thank you :). I am currently using your idea.

Answer (score 1):

To be blunt, your data is not well formed, but that's life :) !  You need to employ what are called "text qualifiers" that will allow the character you're using as a delimiter to appear within the text items you're looking to delimit and not be treated as a delimiter.

An example of what you're after:

`"111"|"AAA"|"1A1"
"222"|"BBB"|"2B2"
"333"|"CC|C"|"3C3"`

Copy/paste the third data row into a new worksheet and then run the Text to Columns wizard (TtCW) on it for delimited text.  In the second step you'll see the "Text qualifier" dropdown on the right hand side.

You may well need to employ VBA to concatenate the data with text qualifiers and then split it again via the TtCW.  Record a macro to see how you can automate it and you'll be able to incorporate it into your code.

Comment: I am doing a form, so I need to used a VBA.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses Get & Transform without vba (requires recent Excel or Power Query addon). Worked fine for me on your data, leaving CC¦C in column B.

Get data from range

Split all using | delimiter

Right click last column -> Split by ¦ delimiter

Rename Column headers

Comment: I am doing a form so I need to used a VBA.

Comment: Text-to-columns with VBA is your best bet then, the other answer looks good.